# Retrieve indexes of value in array

Tags: php

Is it possible to search an array for a given value and return all the indexes at which the value was found? So for this array:

```
["Red","Green","Red","Blue"]
```

I need

```
[0,2]
```

with regard to a search for "Red". Searching for "Yellow" in this case would return an empty array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
$array = ["Red","Green","Red","Blue"];
$output = array_keys($array, "Red");
```

The `$output` will be `[0,2]`

Comment: how can i forget about `array_keys()` and started written about `foreach()`. so silly. +1 to you

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant. but it doesn't really work if we want to search for more than two values. But that's okay I guess for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```php
$input = ["Red","Green","Red","Blue"];
$x = "Red";
$keys = array_keys(array_filter($input, function ($v) use ($x) { return $v === $x;}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$arr = ["Red","Green","Red","Blue"];
$valueToSearchFor = ["Red"];
$keys = array_keys(array_filter($arr, function ($val1) use ($valueToSearchFor) { // filter the first array
    return array_filter($valueToSearchFor, function ($val) use ($val1) { // use the first array's value
        return $val == $val1; // compare them and then return them
    });
}));
var_dump($keys) // array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(2) }
```

First we filter the array then take the values from the first filter to another filter then we match the arrays and we return them. This works for multiple values too.

```php
$arr = ["Red","Green","Red","Blue"];
$valueToSearchFor = ["Red", "Blue"];
$keys = array_keys(array_filter($arr, function ($val1) use ($valueToSearchFor) {
    return array_filter($valueToSearchFor, function ($val) use ($val1) {
        return $val == $val1;
    });
}));
var_dump($keys) // array(3) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array with foreach:

```
foreach($input_arr as $key => $value){
  if($value == 'Red'){
    needed_key_arr[] = $key;
  }
}
```

Also, if you can have an array of values you what to search use:

```
$lookup_arr = ['Red', 'Green'];
foreach($input_arr as $key => $value){
  if(in_array($value, $lookup_arr)){
    needed_key_arr[] = $key;
  }
}
```